# Is there a way to mmap a stdin?

Tags: c, unix

I have a following problem:

My job is to write a program that takes unsigned integer numbers that are passed to it through stdin and print out only the numbers that have more than 2 bits set to one. How should I do it efficiently? I did a version of a program where I read the numbers from a file using mmap, and it's quite quick. I read it like a very big *char buffer and using strtol I 'scrub' out each number and do my check and whatnot.

Is there a way to operate on a string passed through stdin the same way? I though about buffering using fread, but there is a problem, where the buffer cuts off the number (meaning if i pass "1024 35" and I have a 6 byte buffer I will get "1024 3"), and I shudder to think how to get around that.

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h> /* mmap() is defined in this header */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"apue.h"
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int fdin, fdout;
 char *src, *dst;
 struct stat statbuf;


 /* open the input file */
 if ((fdin = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
   {printf("can't open %s for reading", argv[1]);return 1;}



 /* find size of input file */
 if (fstat (fdin,&statbuf) < 0)
    {printf("fstat error");return 1;}





 /* mmap the input file */
 if ((src = mmap (0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fdin, 0))
   == (caddr_t) -1)
   {printf("mmap error for input");return 1;}

  char* beg=src;
  long x;
  char* end=&src[statbuf.st_size-1];
  while(src<end)
  {     
        beg=src;
        x = strtol (src,&src,10);
        if(!((x != 0) && ((x & (~x + 1)) == x)))
            fwrite(beg, 1, (int)(src-beg), stdout);    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/EVhG3x79

Comment: The numbers, are they passed as text, or directly fwrite'd into the stream in their `unsigned int` form?

Comment: why mmap? unless you have some way of detecting when a number cuts off v.s. a number that NATURALLY ends right where you stopped reading stdin, you'd still be in the same boat. e.g. if you're passing `1 2 3` and whatever's in stdin ends right after the two. how do you know that 2 is completed, and isn't actually suppsoed to be `1 23456 3`?

Comment: They are passed as text.

Comment: Then you'll probably spend more time on converting the text to numbers than you could gain using `mmap`. Keep it simple.

Comment: Meaning that how should I approach this problem? Is my currect way of thinking completely wrong? Is there a way to read a string from stdin as comfortably as I would operate on a file using mmap?

Comment: to anwer the question in the title: memory mapping will not work if the data source is a terminal or a pipe and not a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the expected solution is how to count the ones and not how to read from stdin.

```
int count_ones(int n);
```

means the question is how to implement the count_ones efficiently.
and your main just should look like this:

```
int main()
{
  int x;
  cin>>x;
  if( count_ones(x)>2){
    cout<<x<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I think the expected answer is:

1. use array size 256
2. for each byte(=unsigned char) put in the array in its place the count of ones (can be: from 0 to 8)
3. split each number to its bytes and sum the ones on each of the bytes.
4. return the result